# How can I select which text will be used when sharing with AddToAny?

Tags: javascript, sharing

We are using [AddToAny](http://www.addtoany.com/) to put share buttons on our pages. When sharing to FaceBook for example, it picks the correct title, but it picks the wrong text. My guess is that it uses the first `<p>` it finds. This is in many cases not correct, since we have `<p>`s in a column on the left of the page, but the main text is in a bigger area (later on in the source).

Can I tell AddToAny which text to use (with an id for example)? If not, does some other service support this (AddThis, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afraid it's facebook that extracts the text, add2any just passes URL & title.

update: use meta-tags [as described on facebook developer wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Share/Specifying_Meta_Tags)

Comment: Ah, I see! I'll investigate further.

Comment: AddToAny actually had a FAQ entry about this: http://www.addtoany.com/buttons/faq/#facebook